# C++ WinRT - RawGameController on wireless game controller with USB adapter always detected ON?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, wifi, adapter, gamepad

I am using a generic wireless game controller with USB adapter ( non-Bluetooth ) plugged into PC.

With RawGameController API, I found out source below always reported this gamepad  always ON, even it is originally turned OFF at startup.

```
for (auto e : RawGameController::RawGameControllers())
{
    auto it = std::find(m_gamepad.db.begin(), m_gamepad.db.end(), e);

    // db...is std::vector<RawGameController>
    if (it == m_gamepad.db.end())
    {
        m_gamepad.db.insert(m_gamepad.db.begin() + m_gamepad.count, e);

        m_gamepad.count++;
    }
}
```

The above source is derived from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.rawgamecontroller

In this case how to correctly detect the wireless gamepad with USB adapter when it is turned on or some other reason ?

However, for Bluetooth Gamepads are working fine for both ON and OFF.

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you share which gamepad you're using? My guess is the gamepad will always appear to be connected as long as the USB receiver is plugged in. Maybe there's a way you can query the receiver to ask if it has a connected gamepad.

Comment: Sure, https://shopee.com.my/XON-WIRELESS-2.4G-SINGLE-SHOCK-USB-CONTROLER-VIBRATE-WL706-i.20052941.553129144 
 
 Since, it is a non-standard brand and is better to give its parameters retrieved such as here: 

vid=9571
pid=1397
buttons=13
axis=4
switchpos=1

Comment: Thanks! I think this gamepad just isn't supported by the browser you're using.